# Tilt (kramdown) preventing ERB processing when rendering markdown

Tags: ruby, haml, erb, middleman, kramdown

I am building a website with [Middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/). I am storing a lot of information in data files, as I am going to use the same information on multiple pages. (Partials wouldn't work for me, as same text from data can be used with different HTML tags or be slightly modified for different pages.)

I want to write *markdown in data files* and then use it *within HAML templates* for specific pages. When I try to create relative links to other pages while using a reference to other data file, resulting HTML is not what it should be.

`data/pages.yaml`:

```
pageA:
  link: /it-can-change-A.html
  name: PageA name
  info: Some other related info

pageB:
  link: /subject-to-change-B.html
  name: PageB name
  info: Some other related info

pageC:
  link: /some-C.html
  name: PageC name
  info: Some other related info
```

`data/faq.yaml`:

```
testcase: Some text with [internal link to page A](ref.pageA). And *another* [internal reference](ref.pageB).

verbatim: Some text with [internal link to page A](/it-can-change-A.html). And *another* [internal reference](/subject-to-change-B.html).
```

While trying to find the root cause of this issue, I have tested various ways to "extract" relative links from the data file and put them in the HAML template. My end goal is to get the case (5) to work.

I commented on the results of each piece of code directly in my `test.html.md.erb.haml`:

*Please note that HAML has to be processed before ERB, so .haml needs to be the last extension. If .erb and .haml extensions switch places, case (3) and (4) below will produce different output.*

```
/ Pure ERB; ERB is processed before markdown => :)
(1) This is just some text with [ERB link to first page](<%= data.pages.pageA.link %>) and *another* one [to second page](<%= data.pages.pageB.link %>). 

/ ERB inside HAML tag; markdown is not processed => :|
.haml
    (2) This is just some text with [ERB link to first page](<%= data.pages.pageA.link %>) and *another* one [to second page](<%= data.pages.pageB.link %>). 

/ Helper used WITHOUT a tag; ERB is processed before markdown => :)
(3)
= refonly(data.faq.testcase) 

/ Helper used WITH a tag; ERB is processed, but markdown is not => :|
.question1
    (4)
    = refonly(data.faq.testcase)

/ "Tilt-powered" helper used WITHIN a tag; trying to process markdown with Tilt results in "%=%20data.pages.pageA.link%20%" links. Expected behavior: ERB should be processed first, then Tilt should process markdown with actual relative links being the same as in .question1 above => :(
.question2
    (5)
    = mymarkdown(data.faq.testcase)

/ Helper with Tilt to process verbatim text; markdown is processed correctly => :)
.question3
    (6)
    = justmarkdown(data.faq.verbatim)
```

Helpers used in template above:

```
def refonly(text)
    text.gsub(/ref\.(page[A-Z])/,"<\%= data.pages.\\1.link %>")
end

def mymarkdown(text)
    newtext = refonly(text)
    Tilt['markdown'].new(context: @app) { newtext }.render
end

def justmarkdown(text)
    Tilt['markdown'].new(context: @app) { text }.render
end
```

The purpose of the first helper is to change easy-to-write reference inside data file (ref.pageName) to ERB code, same as one used in (1). The purpose of the second helper is to render markdown in the case where `.md` template extension itself fails to render it automatically. The purpose of the last helper is to show that Tilt can render verbatim text properly in (6), but it when it accepts same text as a variable, it can't provide same output in (5).

A. When I use "pure ERB" (1), or `refonly` helper without HAML tag (3), output is as expected: relative path is sourced from data file and then markdown is processed by default markdown engine (kramdown) thanks to `.md` template extension.

B. When I try to use HAML tag, either directly with ERB code (2), or with `refonly` helper (4), ERB is processed correctly and put into the output. However, markdown is not processed for some reason automatically, even though `.md` extension is used directly after `.html`, hence markdown should be processed after HAML and ERB bits are finished.

C. In order to "force" markdown rendering, I am using Tilt in my second helper. My intention was to pass text returned by `refonly` (which has correct markdown syntax with intended link extracted from data) to Tilt. My expectation was that Tilt would simply render verbatim text passed to it in (5), just as it does in (6). Instead, resulting link points to `%=%20data.pages.pageA.link%20%`, which seems to be HTML code to display ERB code verbatim. So, it looks like passing `newtext` variable to Tilt somehow stops ERB processing and ERB code is passed directly to markdown.

My **primary** question is: how can I make sure that Tilt gets the proper text with a relative link (as returned by `refonly`) and produces expected output in (5)?

My **secondary** question: why markdown is not processed automatically by Middleman in cases described under B.?

I assume that answer to my primary question requires knowledge of the Ruby and Tilt, while the answer to my secondary question requires knowledge of Middleman. While the solution to my primary issue would be great, answer to the secondary question might allow to skip Tilt altogether and hence solve the problem in an easier way.

Comment: Is it required that you use ERB? It seems that by using both ERB and HAML, you are making things more complicated than they need to be, which means more opportunity for confusing errors or misbehaviors

Comment: I am using ERB as a result of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44564396/1226389) to a simpler version of my question. But if there is HAML solution that will work, I am all for skipping ERB :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have HAML parsing correctly, and when you render verbatim links it works, try using a helper to directly inject the links without needing to go to ERB. Since HAML will already run Ruby code, I see no need to pass it through ERB too. I think `eval` will allow you to get the same effect you're using ERB for. Something like this:

```
def refonly(text)
  text.scan(/ref\.(page[A-Z])/).each do |groups|
    page_name = groups[0]
    text.gsub!(/ref\.#{page_name}/, eval("data.pages.#{page_name}.link"))
  end
  text
end
```

EDIT: Scanning the text will allow you to get each page_name so you can loop through each one and replace each page reference with its link.

Comment: Your code was giving me ``(eval):1: unterminated string meets end of file`` error, but I noticed that you left the ERB bit at the end of the ``eval()`` code. I made an edit to your answer to reflect that.

Comment: After my edit, your code kind-of-works. That is, it creates proper HTML code, with the page references replaced with page URL from data. However, this only works properly if there is only reference to one page in the ``data.faq.testcase``. If there is more, as it is the case in MWE and my actual use case, all references are being replaced with the same URL, in this case,``data.pages.pageA.link``.  This is the same issue that [Kathryn's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44564396/1226389) had.

Comment: The only solution I see in order to make it work "globally", that is with a reference to more than one page is to somehow loop through all references in markdown text pulled from data and then do your substitution for all of them. However, I have no idea how to approach this. The other solution would be to figure out why ERB is not processed properly in (5), as then all references' URLs would be the proper ones, without the need to loop through them.

Comment: @Rafal, good catch on the bit of trailing ERB code. While I'm still not sure why ERB isn't being processed properly (I don't use HAML), I was able to get `refonly` to loop through and get the effect I believe you are after.

Comment: This worked great. Thank you! I have been trying to solve this issue for many months and your solution is the only one that really worked. After implementing it, I noticed that I have some text that is not generated using ``mymarkdown`` helper, but in different ways. Do you know if it is possible to run this code, where contents of the page would be passed to the code of this helper in a similar way ``text`` variable is? This would finally solve all my link-related issues. I asked another question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45692859/1226389

Comment: I commented about this on your new question. Basically, I think you'd be better off to try to get the `mymarkdown` helper to output exactly what end result you're looking for rather than try to intercept HAML's output, modify it, and send it back on its way.