# Execute Ruby method on whole page in Middleman

Tags: ruby, regex, middleman

On my Middleman-built website, I need to execute specific Ruby code on the contents of all the pages (templates).

For example, if I had following helper in my `config.rb`:

```
def myexample(text)
    text.gsub("dog","cat")
end
```

And in my `test.html.haml`:

```
= myexample("Some text about a dog.")
```

My previewed and generated `/test.html` would read:

```
Some text about a cat.
```

However, I am using several different ways to output text that needs to be modified, most notably through HAML's `:markdown` filter, so I would prefer not to wrap everything in the `= myexample("Text")` helper.

I would like to be able to run Ruby code that would take contents of all the pages (preferably) or generated HTML output (if the first option is not possible) as an argument passed to such helper.

Ideally, this code would be run in both the development and build environments, but if that's not possible, build is enough.

Is it possible to do so?

PS. In my specific case, I use a shorthand notation to reference other pages and then I use a [regular expression and `eval()` in order to replace them with relative links from data files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45638542/1226389).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just ensure that HAML generates the final HTML you're looking for? What you are doing is definitely unconventional, and you may be making it more complicated than it needs to be. But I also know your actual code is much more complex than this.

Comment: The main issue here is that I have over 100 uses of ``:markdown`` HAML filter, which is used to process block markdown (multiple paragraphs), 20% of which include ``ref.pageA`` references. I have been able to change my partials, so now they are processed by your code from the other question, but those ``:markdown`` HAML filters still have some links that need to be evaluated. I don't want to change all HAML filters to ``mymarkdown()`` helper because it would destroy readability and helper doesn't seem to be able to accept block input (multiple paragraphs) anyway.

Comment: If running the code on the whole page is not possible, then my only solution would be to move all those blocks under ``:markdown`` HAML filter to the data file and then put them into template with ``mymarkdown``. And then I would have to wrap all remaining 1-paragraph bits of text that includes links with ``mymarkdown`` helper as well.

Comment: So you have multiple paragraphs of text (which could have markdown in them) associated with each entry in your data files? Then you're accessing that text from the data files through HAML templates?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

ActionController::Base has the `render_to_string` method which will give you the normal HTML output from rendering a partial or page, but in string format. This would allow you to grab the rendered HTML and modify it before finally rendering it for real as an inline template.

In your controller:

```
rendered_html = render_to_string 'your_template_or_partial'
# do stuff to rendered_html
render inline: rendered_html.html_safe, layout: 'layouts/application'
```

The `html_safe` method makes sure Rails knows it's safe to render this as HTML. You do NOT want to do this if user input is being rendered and you have not sanitized it!!!!

If you don't want it to use a layout when rendering, just remove the :layout argument.

Comment: I would actually recommend using this approach sooner in your code. You may be able to simplify your rendering system quite a bit so it doesn't seem so hacky by using this technique. Maybe something like:
`render_to_string` your HAML template. Run the [substitutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45638542/1226389). Render the markdown with Tilt. Then render your (now inline) template.